# css manipulation happens before rendering so it wont be effective

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux for my current project. I have a button and whenever user click on that it first call the server and load some data and then manipulate the css of some dom elements.
Here is my code:

```
 var allClickableStories = document.getElementById("dummyClickStory" + this.props.story.id);

    $(allClickableStories).click(function () {

        if (!$("#" + this.id + " .expansion-handler").hasClass("show")) {

            var storyId = this.id.replace("dummyClickStory", "");
            thisRef.props.getStoryDetail(storyId, thisRef.props.channel);
            $("#" + this.id + " .expansion-handler").addClass("show");
            $("#" + this.id + " .cutline").addClass("show");
        }
    });
```

Also it is noteworthy that the above code in in componentDidMount to make sure that first render happens. However this does not guarantee that ajax call ( thisRef.props.getStoryDetail) happens before css manipulation and this is exactly where I am stuck at.  what is happenning is the ajax call is sent and then css manipulation fires however ajax call may return after and render will happend and hide the manipulated dom element again.An easy way to fix it is to set asynch to false in jquery ajax call but not a good solution. So  how can I can make sure that first ajax call finishes **and render happens** then css manipulation takes place?

Also just for more info here are my code in Action and reducer:

Action:

```
export function getStoryDetail(storyId,channel){
return dispatch => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3003/json5.txt",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var storyDetatil=[];
            for (var key in data) {
                storyDetatil.push(data[key]);
            }
            var storyDetailObj={"storyArray":storyDetatil,"storyId":storyId, "channel":channel};
            dispatch({
                type: "STORY_EXPANSION",
                payload: storyDetailObj

            });
        }.bind(this)
    });
};
```

}

Reducer:

```
 case "STORY_EXPANSION":
        var tempStateExpansion = state.slice();
        if (action.payload.storyId > -1  && state[0].channel !=undefined) {
            for(var i=0;i<state.length;i++){
                if(state[i].channel.toLowerCase()===action.payload.channel.toLowerCase()){
                    for(var j=0;j<state[i].storiesSnippet.length;j++){
                        if(action.payload.storyId===state[i].storiesSnippet[j].id){
                            tempStateExpansion[i].storiesSnippet[j]=action.payload.storyArray[0];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            tempStateExpansion[0].storiesSnippet[0]=action.payload.storyArray[0];
        }
        state=tempStateExpansion;

        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can not do this with React. You are using jQuery to manipulate the DOM which is basically the opposite approach to React. React manipulates the DOM for you.

What you should do instead is to have a component (you could look at inline styles perhaps: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html) that will rerender based on an updated state.

1. App renders with whatever defaults and fires off ajax request.
2. Ajax response updates the redux store, which through `connect` and a `mapStateToProps` updates the props of a component that should change when the ajax request is fulfilled.
3. Component rerenders based on the new state. The render path has the new styles (possibly inline)

I would recommend running through the TODO List example with redux and React here: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html. Your Redux usage looks alright, it's the React that is problematic.

Here is an example of using a React component which would rerender based on a `data` property of the redux state. It assumes that you would have an application wide CSS that contains definitions for `foo` and `bar` CSS classes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    // If data is present (render a div using CSS from class foo)
    // and put the data in the div asuming it's a string
    if (data) {
      return <div className='foo'>{ data }</div>;
    }
    // If data is not present (render a div using CSS from class bar)
    // Display No Content
    return <div className='bar'>No Content</div>;
  }
}

// Data is an object, but not required as initially it will be undefined
Example.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.object
};

// Map redux state to react props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data
});

// Connect to redux store helper using our mapping function
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Example);
```